# Multicols - start tikzpicture at the top of the paragraph

Tags: multicol

I'd like to ask you about the way to force the tikzpicture at the top of the multicols. The result is below.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,singlespacing]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{geometry}

\lstset{ 
basicstyle=\footnotesize
}

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper,
    inner=1in, 
    outer=1in, 
    top=.6in, 
    bottom=.8in 
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}


\paragraph*{Nice paragraph}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{small}
\begin{itemize}

\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{minipage}

\columnbreak

\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(7,5)(0,0)
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){4}}
\put(4,0){\line(0,1){3}}
\put(0,0){\line(4,3){4}}
\end{picture}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{picture}(7,5)(0,0)
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){4}}
\put(4,0){\line(0,1){3}}
\put(0,0){\line(4,3){4}}
\end{picture}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{small}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

What it produces:
[image]

What I expect:
[image]

Is there any way to force this position?

Comment: Your picture is much larger than the tikzpicture. Add a frame with \fbox to see it. Use `\begin{picture}(4,3)(0,0)`, you should use `\subsection*{Nice paragraph}` for the title or `\paragraph*{Nice paragraph}~\\`  to get a line break

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you. I've missed that thing.

Comment: But I wouldn't use multicols for this type of things - it is difficult to align columns, and the itemize is imho unnecessary too.

Comment: Is there any more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all you need to do is specify the width using `\makebox`, `\parbox` or `minipage` and space them apart with an `\hfill`.  (`Tabularx` is also an option.)  Pictures are normally aligned by their bottoms, but you can use `\raisebox{-\height}{...}` to align their tops.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,singlespacing]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{geometry}

\lstset{ 
basicstyle=\footnotesize
}

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper,
    inner=1in, 
    outer=1in, 
    top=.6in, 
    bottom=.8in 
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Nice paragraph

\begin{small}
\noindent\makebox[0.45\textwidth][l]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\hfill\makebox[0.45\textwidth][l]{%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(3,2)(0,0)
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){4}}
\put(4,0){\line(0,1){3}}
\put(0,0){\line(4,3){4}}
\end{picture}}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{picture}(3,2)(0,0)
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){4}}
\put(4,0){\line(0,1){3}}
\put(0,0){\line(4,3){4}}
\end{picture}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned images]